# Image drop down box

Tags: jquery, button, drop-down-menu

I need to make an image link in my top+left corner of my site, when I click on it, I would  open a drop down box under this image with a preconfigured size. How I can perform this in JQUERY.

```
> image_link______________________________________________              
> |000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000|           
> |000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000| 
> |000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000| 
> |______________________________________________________|
```

as upon ;-).
thanks in advance.`enter code here`

Comment: Please read jQuery documentation before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the jQuery toggle function like so: http://jsfiddle.net/kKGyc/

Comment: thanks the http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ is perfect I have found in addition this http://www.hv-designs.co.uk/2009/02/17/sliding-jquery-menu/